# ASP .NET Razor v3 page never finishes loading

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a simple ASP .NET project (not MVC) that uses two Razor pages. The first page, once loaded, keeps calling the second page via `XMLHttpRequest` object at two-second intervals.

Here is the content of the second page.

```
@{
   <text>0</text>
}
```

All it does is returns a value 0.

Here is the code from the first page that is invoked at two-second intervals:

```
function myFunction() {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          var txt = xhttp.responseText();
          mydisplay(txt);
      }else{
          var msg = xhttp.readyState.toString() + " " + xhttp.status.toString();
          mydisplay(msg);
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "Page2.cshtml", true);
      xhttp.send();
   }
}
```

When the first page is run, I keep getting `readyState` values of 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, and so on but I never get the value 4 (that is used to indicate that page loading is completed).

I am wondering if I need to do something more in my second page to inform that the page operation has been completed. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content type served by Razor page by default is text/HTML. As as result, I guess the client assumes an end-html tag. I changed the content type to "application/json" and now am returning a json object. The client now does get a `readyState`value of 4.